# Can't close dropdown in twitter bootstrap 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a navbar and added a `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` effect on two dropdowns

This how it works:

If i hover my mose to the dropdown the the `.mouseenter()` event is triggered and the contents of the dropdown will slide down and if i unhover my mouse to the dropdown it will slide up and hide the contents.

**Problem:**

When i unhover the mouse on the first dropdown, it won't hide and when i try in the second i hovered it and it didn't work, i clicked it it worked but won't hide when i unhover my mouse to the second dropdown.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakobaindreas11/32S7a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script has to be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FQvpZ/)